# Reference: Betti Numbers of the free loop space are finite

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

let $M$ be a compact, simply connected Riemannian manifold with dimension $< \infty$. I'm looking for a reference that
$$ \dim H_k(\Lambda M, \mathbb{Z}) < \infty, $$

is true in that case. Here 
$$\Lambda M= \{c :S^1 \rightarrow M| c\text{ is square summable and absolutely continous}\}$$ is the free loop space.

Thanks,

Mick

Comment: Is $k$ fixed here?

Comment: This can be proved using the Serre spectral sequences for the fibrations $\Omega M\to\Lambda M\to M$ and $\Omega M\to PM\to M$, but I do not know where this is spelled out.

Comment: No, it isn't fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As Neil Strickland points out, for a fixed $k$ the Betti number of the free loop space is indeed finite. However it is worth pointing out that the sequence of Betti numbers $b_k(\Lambda M)$ is *unbounded* whenever the rational cohomology algebra of $M$ requires at least two generators. This is the main result of

D. Sullivan, M. Vigue-Poirrier, *[The homology theory of the closed geodesic problem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214433729)*. 
J. Differential Geometry 11 (1976), no. 4, 633–644,

and was an early application of Sullivan's theory of minimal models.

Comment: Concerning the growth of Betti numbers of free loop spaces, it is worth mentionning also the papers of Pascal Lambrechts *On the Betti numbers of the free loop space of a coformal space* (JPAA 2001) and *The Betti numbers of the free loop space of a connected sum* ( J. London Math. Soc. 2001).

Comment: Hi Mark, can I ask a question - does this finiteness of Betti number hold only for simply connected manifolds? How about non-simply  connected ones?

Comment: In the non-simply connected case you can easily have infinite $0$-th and $1$-st Betti numbers, e.g. if $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Z}$ then $\Lambda M$ has infinitely many path components. Not sure about the higher Betti numbers.